# Froala Editor Image Upload Error

Tags: php, html

I have read the [documentation of Froala editor](https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/server-integrations/php-image-upload). And tried to reproduce this example at my local server.

But, I cannot make it work. Code is the same as the documentation, but my folder structure is as follows:

```
cac/web/
    uploads/
    upload.php
```

I keep getting errors. No matter how I change the image path. I just don't understand too much how should I place the paths with my given folder structure.

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  move_uploaded_file(/cac/web/uploads/069fc534ceb01b2217e12b72583aff80005cb3e8.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cac/web/upload.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpQJYxaP' to '/cac/web/uploads/069fc534ceb01b2217e12b72583aff80005cb3e8.png' in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cac/web/upload.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />
{"link":"/uploads/069fc534ceb01b2217e12b72583aff80005cb3e8.png"}
```

Comment: make sure the web server has permissions to access the folder in which you are trying to move the image

Answer (score 0):

Changing line `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/uploads/" . $name);` to `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], getcwd() . "/uploads/" . $name);` should get it to work.

Comment: Thank you, but no, not working. I am sure the problem is path related, but I cannot solve it. I have tried all posible paths, relative, absolute... Localhost side and hosting side...

Comment: Do you get the same error? If yes, then try: `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], getcwd() . "/uploads/" . $name);`

Comment: Hi @st3fan, I figured it out finally, as you mention with getcwd(), it was a matter of relative / absolute paths... Thanks anyway!